# Auto-generation of code in order to mass produce. Is this sensible?

Tags: code-generation

Our company plans to auto-generate our projects from the domain area up-to the presentation layer so that we can **mass produce** software. The idea is we can produce a project within 24 hours. I think this is possible but that's not my concern.

What are the ramifications of such plan? I just think that the quality of software produced from such grandeur idea is below good quality. First, clients have varying requirements. Assuming we can standardize what's common among them, there are still requirements that will be beyond our original template.

Second, how can such software be reliable if not fully tested? Does a 24 hour period can cover a full unit/integration/other types of test?

At the end, it appears we won't be able to hit the 24 hour target thereby defeating our original purpose.

I just believe it's better to build quality software than mass producing them. How would I tell my boss that their idea is wrong?

Comment: What's being generated? the code itself or is it some kind of modular setup where the modules are selected and then projects are created (as in copied) according to that?

Comment: How big is that "domain area"?

Comment: This is a great opportunity to do formal verification on the program skeletons.

Comment: @thehj, that's the problem. It really depends on the client's requirements. Even if we standardize the similar requirements, some are still beyond what we originally designed for. The other idea is to manually code those that vary. But then that defeats the whole purpose of within 24-hour auto-generation of code. It wouldn't be 24 hours anymore.

Comment: Hehe, this is hilarious! 24 hours to create new projects! The age-old dream of writing the one single line that does it all! If this thing were mathematically possible, it would have been done a long time ago. Imagine the money you can make!! That's probably what your boss has in mind :-) Here's a couple of subtle "hints" you can give to your boss: http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Productivity

Comment: Exactly. It's all about the money, thought I wouldn't mind having more money :) But it's like his dream is to create a skyscraper within 24 hours which is utterly impossible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think this is sensible.

In order to build a system that can auto-generate *any* kind of software that would fill *any* kind of requirement, you will kind of have to implement more then the softwares you plan to generate.

Auto-generated code is great, when you have some repetitive tasks, information, or components, that are similar enough to enable you to make a one time effort to generate all repetitions.

But trying to write a system to produce any kind of project is not feasible. In order to meet a wide enough range of supported projects, your system will have to allow a very wide set of capabilities to describe project configuration and behavior, and the time required to describe each project's behavior will not necessarily be shorter than the time it would have taken to implement the project in the first place. You will just end up developing a development environment, and implementing projects in your own language.

So, instead, why not just take an existing development environment that is already available? Like Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should have a big library reprository and stuff everything that could be reusable in it. This way, the software you have to write would be very small. There could be documentation templates associated with the library and you would just have to C&P them.

However, it takes time to build such a library.

[Or do it this way.](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2007-09-03/)

Comment: +1. There's a paradigm for this kind of thing since the 1950s, and its called libraries.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. I have a reusable library (particularly jars). The templates are based on the Template Method Pattern. But what our boss wants is complete auto-generation of code. Assuming Company A wants to automate their inventory system. They just tell us their products. And within 24 hours...boom...our magic software is ready....sounds ridiculous really.